# How to set automatic build for Codemagic?

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I want to set automatic build on `Codemagic` whenever there is a merge on `Develop` branch

Here is what i have set up

[image]

But the build does not happen when there is a merge.

Comment: the docs say that build on merge is `not supported for apps from custom sources`, where is your repository hosted?

Comment: @ZviKarp on azure devops

Comment: ahh, so that might be the reason. read https://docs.codemagic.io/building/automatic-build-triggering/#webhooks for custom solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you use repository that hosted not in GitHub, Bitbucket or GitLab you need to add webhook to the repository manually as described here https://docs.codemagic.io/building/automatic-build-triggering/#webhooks

Codemagic supports all Git-based repository like Azure DevOps or self-hosted repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't the owner or creator of the repo on GitHub you can't add Webhooks by yourself or by codemagic so ask the repo creator to add the Webhooks
[image]